# simple shell inline provisionning

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, packer

How can I just simple install apache2 package in a packer template for virtualbox-iso Ubuntu and the shell inline provisionning ?

I'm testing this template :

```
{
"builders": [{
    "boot_command": [
        "<esc><wait>",
        "<esc><wait>",
        "<enter><wait>",
        "/install/vmlinuz<wait>",
        " auto<wait>",
        " console-setup/ask_detect=false<wait>",
        " console-setup/layoutcode=fr<wait>",
        " console-setup/modelcode=pc105<wait>",
        " debconf/frontend=noninteractive<wait>",
        " debian-installer=fr_FR<wait>",
        " fb=false<wait>",
        " initrd=/install/initrd.gz<wait>",
        " kbd-chooser/method=fr<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/layout=fr<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/variant=fr<wait>",
        " locale=fr_FR<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_domain=vm<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_hostname=vagrant<wait>",
        " noapic<wait>",
        " preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg<wait>",
        " -- <wait>",
        "<enter><wait>"
    ],
    "boot_wait": "20s",
    "disk_size": 20480,
    "guest_additions_path": "VBoxGuestAdditions_{{.Version}}.iso",
    "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
    "http_directory": "http",
    "headless": false,
    "iso_checksum": "0501c446929f713eb162ae2088d8dc8b6426224a",
    "iso_checksum_type": "sha1",
    "iso_url": "http://mirrors.mit.edu/ubuntu-releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso",
    "output_directory": "packer-ubuntu-14.04-amd64-virtualbox",
    "shutdown_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S shutdown -P now",
    "ssh_username": "vagrant",
    "ssh_password": "vagrant",
    "ssh_port": 22,
    "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
    "type": "virtualbox-iso",
    "vboxmanage": [
        [
            "modifyvm",
            "{{.Name}}",
            "--memory",
            "1024"
        ],
        [
            "modifyvm",
            "{{.Name}}",
            "--cpus",
            "1"
        ]
    ],
    "virtualbox_version_file": ".vbox_version",
    "vm_name": "packer-ubuntu-14.04-amd64"
}],
"post-processors": [{
    "output": "builds/ubuntu-14.04.box",
    "type": "vagrant"
}],
"provisioners": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "execute_command": "echo '{{user `ssh_pass`}}' | {{ .Vars }} sudo -E -S sh '{{ .Path }}'",
        "inline": [
            "echo '%sudo    ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers",
            "sudo apt-get install -y apache2"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This result of test provisionning is :

```
==> virtualbox-iso: Provisioning with shell script: C:\Users\toto\AppData\Local\Temp\packer-shell178737243
virtualbox-iso: [sudo] password for vagrant: Sorry, try again.
virtualbox-iso: [sudo] password for vagrant:
virtualbox-iso: sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

The first step of building Vagrant seem to be good with preseed.cfg file. But this issue arrived when start the provisionning vagrant.

***What is the trick for use a inline provisionning with good right for administration in packer and vagrant system Ubuntu ?***

**technical context**

- OS Host : windows 7 pro
- OS Guest : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- VM technology : VirtualBox 5.0.10 + Vagrant 1.7.4
- VM tools builder : Packer 0.8.6

PS : My template is validated by `packer validate`

Comment: if you use a bash shell you might try to replace `sh` with `bash` in your execute command statement

Comment: good idea but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in this case is that the `ssh_pass` user variable is never set in your Packer template. There are two solutions to this. The easiest option would be to modify your `execute_command` setting in the shell provisioner and hard code the ssh password from your builder...

```
"execute_command": "echo 'vagrant' | {{ .Vars }} sudo -E -S sh '{{ .Path }}'",
```

The more elegant solution would be to add a `variables` block before the `builders` block at the top of your Packer template and use that to set the ssh username and password...

```
"variables": {
    "ssh_user": "vagrant",
    "ssh_pass": "vagrant"
},
```

That would fix your existing `execute_command` in the shell provisioner and you could also use those variables in the builder like so...

```
"shutdown_command": "echo '{{user `ssh_pass`}}' | sudo -S shutdown -P now",
"ssh_username": "{{user `ssh_user`}}",
"ssh_password": "{{user `ssh_pass`}}",
```

That way you would be defining your ssh credentials in one place in your Packer template.

Comment: For this moment I just trying the first solution which run correctly. Thank you Patrick Lee. I will vote for your response when I will try your second solution this evening.

Comment: For the second solution, the build run correctly but impossible to connect into the VM but I ask another question for that. @Patrick Lee : thank you see you later...

Comment: You should also ensure that the `vagrant.sh` script ran, because it enables passwordless sudo inside the VM, which the prompt for a password to sudo shows didn't happen (likely due to the error mentioned in this answer).